# Multiple timerTask

Tags: android

In My app I want to do some operations on every 3mins, 5mins, 10 mins. In android is there any API
to do it in single Timer/thread. What is the best way to that ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use multiple TimerTasks? In each of them you can call some synchronized method which will guarantee that only 1 thread runs it at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to create Timers in Android is to use Handler, as suggested [here](http://www.muktosoft.com/timer-in-android-the-better-way/). You could create one Handler task for every interval you need.

One thing to notice is that if you need long intervals (like 3 or 5 minutes you've mentioned), your application may not running for so long. In that a case you can use and [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).